# How to share text on whatsapp in android?

Tags: android

I am using a button in a listview and want to share text on whatsapp...here is my code...this code is working without taking a listview...but i making a project in which i am using a listview.....

```
 Intent  intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             intent.setType("text/plain");
             intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "Try this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.listviewexample");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: Means button click is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");

    String text = "Try this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.listviewexample";

    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    if (waIntent != null) {
      waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
    } else {
      Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try Ctr+Shilf+O to organize your imports.

Comment: If you are using this inside fragment, then you should use getActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

Comment: If your using it inside list adapter, then you need to pass context from activity to adapter and then you can start activity as context.startActivity(.......);